# Spring + Jersey Integration Issue - SpringScopeContext must be in the Singleton scope

Tags: spring, rest, jersey-2.0, hk2, spring-jersey

I am having trouble integrating Jersey with Spring. I am getting the following exception while starting up the server.

Jersey 2.32, Spring 5.2.12, Weblogic:12.2.1.3

WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2 failure has been detected in a code that does not run in an active Jersey Error scope.
WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The implementation class org.jvnet.hk2.spring.bridge.internal.SpringScopeContext must be in the Singleton scope
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.checkConfiguration(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1722)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.addConfiguration(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2118)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DynamicConfigurationImpl.commit(DynamicConfigurationImpl.java:286)
at org.jvnet.hk2.spring.bridge.internal.SpringBridgeImpl.initializeSpringBridge(SpringBridgeImpl.java:64)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider.initialize(SpringComponentProvider.java:87)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ComponentProviderConfigurator.lambda$null$0(ComponentProviderConfigurator.java:55)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:439)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ComponentProviderConfigurator.lambda$init$1(ComponentProviderConfigurator.java:56)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationConfigurator.createApplication(ApplicationConfigurator.java:98)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationConfigurator.init(ApplicationConfigurator.java:72)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ApplicationHandler.java:290)
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:3880)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:290)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:259)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:311)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:347)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:343)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:294)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:99)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:87)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:31)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:673)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:612)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:2064)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:2041)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1930)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3101)
....
....
....
org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1287)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:333)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:375)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1237)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1168)
at

<Mar 1, 2021 5:33:15,903 AM CST>    <Servlet: "REST Web Application" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "ws.war".
A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:

1. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The implementation class org.jvnet.hk2.spring.bridge.internal.SpringScopeContext must be in the Singleton scope

   at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.checkConfiguration(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1722)
   at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.addConfiguration(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2118)
   at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DynamicConfigurationImpl.commit(DynamicConfigurationImpl.java:286)
   at org.jvnet.hk2.spring.bridge.internal.SpringBridgeImpl.initializeSpringBridge(SpringBridgeImpl.java:64)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider.initialize(SpringComponentProvider.java:87)
   Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
   Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The implementation class org.jvnet.hk2.spring.bridge.internal.SpringScopeContext must be in the Singleton scope
   at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.checkConfiguration(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1722)
   at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.addConfiguration(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2118)
   at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DynamicConfigurationImpl.commit(DynamicConfigurationImpl.java:286)
   at org.jvnet.hk2.spring.bridge.internal.SpringBridgeImpl.initializeSpringBridge(SpringBridgeImpl.java:64)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider.initialize(SpringComponentProvider.java:87)
   Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

> 

Comment: how did you apply the hk2-spring bridge?

Comment: I didn't configured any thing manually, didn't saw anything in this https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/tree/master/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp .

Comment: Have you tried it in a different server?

Comment: No, we have to use only weblogic.

Comment: You should try a different server so you can rule out whether or not WebLogic is the problem.

Comment: Let's assume if weblogic is the problem, what are the ways we could fix it.

Comment: Why don't we worry about that when/if we get there.

Comment: Also you need to post more information about your environment. Just posting a stack trace is hardly enough for anyone to Abe to help you. People are just going to be throwing guesses at you if they do not have enough information to reproduce the problem.